# Should I cache results of functions involving mass file I/O in a node.js server app?

Tags: node.js, express, io

I'm writing my first 'serious' Node/Express application, and I'm becoming concerned about the number of O(n) and O(n^2) operations I'm performing on every request. The application is a blog engine, which indexes and serves up articles stored in markdown format in the file system. The contents of the articles folder do not change frequently, as the app is scaled for a personal blog, but I would still like to be able to add a file to that folder whenever I want, and have the app include it without further intervention.

#### Operations I'm concerned about

- When /index is requested, my route is iterating over all files in the directory and storing them as objects
- When a "tag page" is requested (/tag/foo) I'm iterating over all the articles, and then iterating over their arrays of tags to determine which articles to present in an index format

Now, *I know that this is probably premature optimisation* as the performance is still satisfactory over <200 files, but definitely not lightning fast. And I also know that in production, measures like this wouldn't be considered necessary/worthwhile unless backed by significant benchmarking results. But as this is purely a learning exercise/demonstration of ability, and as I'm (perhaps excessively) concerned about learning optimal habits and patterns, I worry I'm committing some kind of sin here.

#### Measures I have considered

I get the impression that a database might be a more typical solution, rather than filesystem I/O. But this would mean monitoring the directory for changes and processing/adding new articles to the database, a whole separate operation/functionality. If I did this, would it make sense to be watching that folder for changes even when a request isn't coming in? Or would it be better to check the freshness of the database, *then* retrieve results from the database? I also don't know how much this helps ultimately, as database calls are still async/slower than internal state, aren't they? Or would a database query, e.g. `articles where tags contain x` be O(1) rather than O(n)? If so, that would clearly be ideal.

Also, I am beginning to learn about techniques/patterns for caching results, e.g. a property on the function containing the previous result, which could be checked for and served up without performing the operation. But I'd need to check if the folder had new files added to know if it was OK to serve up the cached version, right? But more fundamentally (and this is the essential newbie query at hand) *is it considered OK to do this?* Everyone talks about how node apps should be stateless, and this would amount to maintaining state, right? Once again, I'm still a fairly raw beginner, and so reading the source of mature apps isn't always as enlightening to me as I wish it was.

**Also** *have I fundamentally misunderstood how routes work in node/express?* If I store a variable in index.js, are all the variables/objects created by it destroyed when the route is done and the page is served? If so I apologise profusely for my ignorance, as that would negate basically everything discussed, and make maintaining an external database (or just continuing to redo the file I/O) the only solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, the request and response objects that are part of each request last only for the duration of a given request and are not shared by other requests.  They will be garbage collected as soon as they are no longer in use.

But, module-scoped variables in any of your Express modules last for the duration of the server.  So, you can load some information in one request, store it in a module-level variable and that information will still be there when the next request comes along.

Since multiple requests can be "in-flight" at the same time if you are using any async operations in your request handlers, then if you are sharing/updating information between requests you have to make sure you have atomic updates so that the data is shared safely.  In node.js, this is much simpler than in a multi-threaded response handler web server, but there still can be issues if you're doing part of an update to a shared object, then doing some async operation, then doing the rest of an update to a shared object.  When you do an async operation, another request could run and see the shared object.

When not doing an async operation, your Javascript code is single threaded so other requests won't interleave until you go async.

---

It sounds like you want to cache your parsed state into a simple in-memory Javascript structure and then intelligently update this cache of information when new articles are added.

Since you already have the code to parse your set of files and tags into in-memory Javascript variables, you can just keep that code.  You will want to package that into a separate function that you can call at any time and it will return a newly updated state.

Then, you want to call it when your server starts and that will establish the initial state.

All your routes can be changed to operate on the cached state and this should speed them up tremendously.

Then, all you need is a scheme to decide when to update the cached state (e.g. when something in the file system changed).  There are lots of options and which to use depends a little bit on how often things will change and how often the changes need to get reflected to the outside world.  Here are some options:

1. You could register a file system watcher for a particular directory of your file system and when it triggers, you figure out what has changed and update your cache.  You can make the update function as dumb (just start over and parse everything from scratch) or as smart (figure out what one item changed and update only that part of the cache) as it is worth doing.  I'd suggest you start simple and only invest more in it when you're sure that effort is needed.
2. You could just manually rebuild the cache once every hour.  Updates would take an average of 30 minutes to show, but this would take 10 seconds to implement.
3. You could create an admin function in  your server to instruct the server to update its cache now.  This might be combined with option 2, so that if you added new content, it would automatically show within an hour, but if you wanted it to show immediately, you could hit the admin page to tell it to update its cache.

Comment: Wow thanks, you've made everything 100% clear now. Given how much longer it would take to write a new article, and the finite amount of article ideas a given person might have, options 2 & 3 sound like the way to go. Would it be too ugly a hack to have the admin function triggered by a route like mydumbblog.com/update? Are there any security concerns here **other than** the risk of someone writing a script to repeated hit that URL as fast as possible, which I'd mitigate via some kind of minimalist authentication, or via simply throttling it (if this has run in the last minute, do nothing)?

Comment: @Toadfish - Glad to help.  If this answered your question, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer.

Comment: @Toadfish - Exposing an unauthenticated route that rebuilds the cache has no security ramifications other than denial of service on the server or overloading of the server by over zealous hitting of that route.  As you say, you could throttle its use to protect yourself or you could just require a secret password in the URL or in a `.post()` request (which would probably be my preference).